# iphone how to access a custom cell outside of cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: iphone

i have set up a tableview with custom cells. customCell is a class.
heres the code for a more accurate view:

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

 NSManagedObject *object = (NSManagedObject *)[entityArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

 NSString *cellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"asd%d", indexPath.row];

 customCell *cell = [[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier] autorelease];
 //i tried setting a tag but dunno how to call it afterwards
     [cell setTag:indexPath.row];

 if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"customCell" owner:self options:nil];
  cell = [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];
    }

 if (cell.imagen != nil) {
  [[cell imageView] setImage:[cell imagen]];
 } else { /* setup image... */ }
    }


    -(void) webImageReady:(WebImage *)downloadedImage imageView:(UIImageView *)imageView cellTag:(NSInteger *)cTag
    { 
     // This is the part where i want to access cell.imagen, this is actually wrong...
     [[[imageView.superview viewWithTag:cTag] imagen] setImagen:downloadedImage.Image];
     [imageView setImage:downloadedImage.Image];

    }
```

Ok. now i want to access (reference) the cell.imagen property from a method outside cellForRowAtIndexPath, more precisely at a selector for a download finished (delegated)
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't refer to the cell outside the cell creation method, you should consider the case the cell was rendered but while getting the image was scrolled out the dealloced or even reused for another cell, one way to solve it is to have image view array or something similar.

I think you should try using a third party lib that already doing it(among other things) called Three20. It have an object call TTImageView that gets a URL and loads it in the background, it solves all of the cases along with optimized caching

Comment: im having trouble linking Three20 to my project, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I'll be glad to help, anyway there is complete help on the Three20 project.

Comment: Thanks! i followed the tutorial posted at three20.info and it works when i run it simulator but not on the device. the error is weird too:

Comment: “EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION”.
And xcode redirects me to TTImageView.m; - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame

Comment: Ok done some research.. I think this might be the solution: http://groups.google.com/group/three20/browse_thread/thread/9e0361058a2900d4/95094f97345dd7ab

Comment: Yep, that did the trick, along with "-all_load" in the linker flags on all targets AND executables build settings

Answer (score 1):

Do it inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath` if the image is downloaded, and on successful download of the image do `[tableview setNeedsDisplay]`

Comment: Actually this doesn't work, but you can access the visible cells at any time (UItableView visibleCells), and others will be accessed in cellForRowAtIndexPath when they become visible (again)